# How to take picture from front camera in android2.2

Tags: android

can anybody tell How to take picture from front camera in android2.2 can anybody provide sample code

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Camera API with the right camera index:

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera .getParameters();
parameters.set("camera-id", 2);
camera .setParameters(parameters);
```

Don't forget to set the permissions correctly:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Please note that in most cases it will be camera #2, maybe there is another automatic way to find out.
You try this one for now. If I'll find something automatic I'll update the post.

And you can take the complete code from here (just replace the Camera.open):
[Camera Tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html)

Comment: Sorry, missed the android 2.2 thing. It is supported only starting from 2.3. See my edited answer above

Comment: I got error in samsung galaxy tab device but running in emulator

Comment: I don't have access of usb port so i am not able to check eception .I used this tutorial code and set the parameter. can you check?

Comment: You can send the logcat by email to yourself and post it here. For example, install: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.js.Error&feature=search_result

Comment: I dont How to send logcat to mymail can you give code ? and how to post

Comment: Install the app on the link I gave you, run your app...once you get the exception, run the installed app and you will be able to send the logcat

Comment: @lioro I have image view and button in one activity if user click button i have to show preview front face  camera  to user from user click the button capture the image  and display it in imageview can you tell how to do>

Comment: Well this saved me more hours of confusion. Why couldnt eclipse warn me that I was using non-permissioned features.